# Texture Won't Appear - GLUT OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut, texture-mapping

I'm having problems trying to load textures in an OpenGL GLUT project using classes.
Here's some code that includes the texturing stuff:

Declaring a Textured Model from a subclass of a model class.

`TextureModel * title = new TextureModel("Box.obj", "title.raw");`

Constructor method of TextureModel subclass:

```
TextureModel(string fName, string tName) : Model(fName), textureFile(tName)
{   
    material newMat = {{0.63,0.52,0.1,1.0},{0.63,0.52,0.1,1.0},{0.2,0.2,0.05,0.5},10};
    Material = newMat;
    // enable texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    loadcolTexture(textureFile);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureRef);
    // specify the filtering method
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // associate the image read in to the texture to be applied
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, 256, 256, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_array);
}
```

Texture loading function to read in data in RAW file:

```
int loadcolTexture(const string fileName) {
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::binary );

if (!inFile.good())
{
    cerr  << "Can't open texture file " << fileName << endl;
    return 1;
}
inFile.seekg (0, ios::end);
int size = inFile.tellg();
image_array = new char [size];
inFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
inFile.read (image_array, size);
inFile.close();
return 0;}
```

Method to draw the triangles:

```
virtual void drawTriangle(int f1, int f2, int f3, int t1, int t2, int t3, int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureRef);
    glNormal3fv(&normals[n1].x);
    glTexCoord2f(textures[t1].u, textures[t1].v);
    glVertex3fv(&Model::vertices[f1].x);

    glNormal3fv(&normals[n2].x);
    glTexCoord2f(textures[t2].u, textures[t2].v);
    glVertex3fv(&Model::vertices[f2].x);

    glNormal3fv(&normals[n3].x);
    glTexCoord2f(textures[t3].u, textures[t3].v);
    glVertex3fv(&Model::vertices[f3].x);
    glEnd();
}
```

I also have Lighting, Depth Testing and Double Buffering enabled.

Models and Lighting work fine, but the textures don't appear. Any reasons why it won't work will be great.

Comment: You're at least missing a call to `glBindTexture` in the `TextureModel` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the comment, I see a few things here:

1. As mentioned in the comment, you need to bind a texture before you can upload data to it. Once you generate the texture with `glGenTextures`, you need to set it to be the active texture before you try to load data or set set parameters with `glTexParameteri`
2. You're building mipmaps, but not using them. Either set the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` to utilize the mipmaps, or don't build them in the first place. As is you're just wasting texture memory.
3. It's not legal to bind a texture inbetween `glBegin`/`glEnd` as you have done in `drawTriangle`. Bind it before the `glBegin`.
4. Please, *please*, **please** start using `glGetError` in your code. This will tell you if you are doing wrong things before you have to come and ask to find your mistakes. (you would have found 2/3 of the mistakes here if you had been using it).